# gettin file contents on the web

Tags: curl, fopen, file-get-contents

I'm trying to get the contents of a site by file_get_contents() and curl functions or even fopen ... but i cant get my desireds result , i'v also set the Cookie , user-agent ,follow_location , ... by stream_context_creat() , but i still cant get anything!
The link i'm trying on is www.tsetmc.com , and what i'm getting is somthing like encoded html like this :

‹ã×SÿÍ[ÛrÛFš¾Ÿªy‡.©}@£Ià–­(íÆY­¥ÍxÖåRA$$!¡.ÉV2©Ú$–åRù)r±ö¨2ñ:òìÔÌEžƒtîöIöïH‚„@ÑC¯wtD7úø}ÿ©\ý ·²“n€²ÃNsµøøíæêaùu—‚? =íÞÒ¿ÞZZ‹»~îv µâ(¢ÌÓ6Ö½ ½hÍÕ,Ì:AÓ\ÞÞZß¾³¶l¢åeÔ{Þûsÿ1üýü^ þ“þ)<¼\mä…WÓVv³æ±Ÿ OâhÿîQ…û›þ~n…YàérËF«™Yd‡-³ê+{GQ+ãQºéñâW²Î±×‰[~g+‹hÄÜ²,8\ÐŽw´›ÙÉâŠ,”­„{hŠzÑQ§ƒ~ÿ{¨ö7h"¾çEÁCtïÎ'CßwaþAš-,®Ä÷Ì¸DúoÖ·ué0œcÚH‚´Ñ‰ýv˜~Ú}ô™§C?7õ;úÍôØØó;i ê¦AÔ^ý-®d¤¡b7ŽÒ`;x$Ç³ÝÏÌNígKäÁž¾¢/¢$ÈŽ’helFéøŒäÌk dylñëñUVƒL^lñk‰Ivâyzª/~’qtôš aA[M³ JÞÔVE¢hX‚và k@Ãë@>¦·O¶ýýOýÃ`AÿxýÖ‡ú¢Ê.qNC:ªÓJ?ŠjZ.ÚâJj¶ƒ½ ñ²ä(€DXyÙÊéw‰öÚAØi/¤‹_-›;’$ÂÓ©°ô)
...........
Can anyone Help me?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are getting compressed content. Use this curl option to overcome this:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "");
```

Comment: Thank you , and i'v also found out that gzdecode() works good!